# What is the best way to protect my computer from virus and screen readers?

Tags: security, anti-virus, screen-capture

I'm an avid Internet poker player.

What is the best way to make sure that I don't have viruses and programs that can read my screen on my computer?

Comment: As an aside, "screen readers" is a name generally used to describe accessibility tools for the sight-impaired rather than malware: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader

Answer (score 3):

1) Run as normal user

I'd add more, but there really isn't any need.

Oh, don't install anything unless you trust the publisher.

Comment: Windows defaults to running as an administrator, so for many people that is considered normal.  So to clarify, I'll say don't run as an administrator (unless you're doing something that specifically requires administrator privileges).

Answer (score 3):

Have a good anti-virus installed and keep it up to date. Avoid untrustworthy sites. Don't install anything unless you know exactly what it is.

Some of these [related questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/antivirus) may help you choose an anti-virus package.